# currently unable to handle this request HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, server, interspire-shopping-cart

I have transferred my shopping cart files from local to live. The shopping cart which i am using is [Interspire](http://www.interspire.com/).

When I load the page, it shows me this error

> currently unable to handle this request.

The domain is http://4living.de/

I hope to discover why it is showing this error.

Comment: Can you add this code on the top of your php main file ? 

`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Show us your code, or we can't help you.

Comment: 500 errors are generated by code issues. Take a look at your server logs for the error messages to determine where the issue may lie.

Comment: Errrrmmmm more information would be a huge help

Comment: No i have not added it.

Comment: after adding it shows me the error that it,s permission issue

Comment: Check if Apache server (httpd service) is running or not. Command: **service httpd status**

Comment: thanks @Xenofexs for the input, it helped in getting to know the root cause of this issue.

Answer (score 14):

Your site is serving a `500 Internal Server Error`.
This can be caused by a number of things, such as:

- File Permissions
- Fatal Code Errors
- Web Server Issues

**EDIT**

As you have highlighted it is a permission issue. You need to ensure that your files are executable by the web server user

Please see below article for some guidance on proper file permissions.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/proper-permissions-for-web-server-s-directory

Comment: Yes it,s file permissions issue thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was having "*(...) unable to handle this request. http error 500*" and found out it was from a *require_once* that was working locally, on a windows machine, with backslash (\) as separator for directories but when i uploaded to my server it stopped working. I changed it to forward slash (/) and now is ok.

```
require_once ( 'cards\cards.php' ); // **http error 500**

require_once ( 'cards/cards.php' ); // OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the statement `include ("fileName.php");` ?

Are you sure that file is in the correct directory?

Answer (score 0):

My take on this for future people watching this:

This could also happen if you're using: `<?` instead of `<?php`.

Answer (score -2):

I found this was caused by adding a new scope variable to the login scope

Comment: Would you mind providing some more details in your answer?